# How do I make a HEAD request by adding custom header fields and parameters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, http-headers

I need to add authorization code and id in the header field and serial no as a parameter as a HEAD request to the server. Sorry for the dumb question, I am very new to Objective C.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code as an example:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
[request setValue:@"123" forHTTPHeaderField:@"ID"];
//Other parameters like this
[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:...
```